# Took gradients through a stateful object

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, gradient-descent

I have begun to learn TensorFlow with the official guide : https://www.tensorflow.org/guide.

My comprehension is struggling with a part of the guide named "Automatic differentiation" and especially "Took gradients through a stateful object".

I don't understand why they said that stateful object stops gradient. The guide gives this piece of code

```
x0 = tf.Variable(3.0)
x1 = tf.Variable(0.0)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  # Update x1 = x1 + x0.
  x1.assign_add(x0)
  # The tape starts recording from x1.
  y = x1**2   # y = (x1 + x0)**2

# This doesn't work.
print(tape.gradient(y, x0))   #dy/dx0 = 2*(x1 + x0)
```

Why the gradient doesn't record `x0`?! Is it this function `.assign_add(x0)` that increments `x1` overshadow `x0`? Is it because `assign_add` will pick the value of `x0` and steal its allocated memory? Is it the right reason or there is another reason that I don't see?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of it as `x1 = tf.Variable(0.0)` has one state i.e. one memory location where values are stored. Then `x1 = tf.assign_add(x0)` changes these stored values in `x1`. However, it does not "attach" new pointers for memory location of `x0`. Hence a trace back on the gradient tape stops at `x1` because it has no further memory address for `x0` which was used to update it. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636943/what-is-a-stateful-object-in-tensorflow).

> Wikipedia: "...a computer program stores data in variables, which represent storage locations in the computer's memory. The contents of these memory locations, at any given point in the program's execution, is called the program's state."

Code below shows two cases:

- `x1.assign_add(x0)` where `tape` cannot reach `x0`.
- `x1 = x0` where tape can reach `x0`.

Try:

```
# Variable
x0 = tf.Variable(3.0)
x1 = tf.Variable(0.0)

# Record
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

  # Update x1 = x1 + x0
  #x1.assign_add(x0) #<-- Traceback NOT possible
  x1 = x0 #<-- Trace back IS possible

  # Tape starts recording from x0
  #y = (x1 + x0)**2 
  y = x1**2  


# Gradient
grad_y_x0 = tape.gradient(y, x0)
print('grad_y_x0:', grad_y_x0)
```

Output:

```
grad_y_x0: tf.Tensor(6.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```